# How to set paragraph indent margins with photoshop script?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I cannot set the indent left and right margins of a paragraph text in photoshop script.

[image]

I already tried:

```
layer.textItem.leftIndent = new UnitValue(100, 'px');
layer.textItem.rightIndent = new UnitValue(100, 'px');

layer.textItem.spaceBefore = new UnitValue(100, 'px');
layer.textItem.spaceAfter = new UnitValue(100, 'px');
```

but nothing will be set. Do you know which property I need to use?

Comment: Looks like `textItem.leftIndent` is broken at Photoshop's end. It can be [coded around.](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/change-left-or-right-indent-via-script/m-p/13978203)

Answer (score 0):

The scriptListener code is ugly, but it works:

```
set_paragraph_indent_margins(100,100);

function set_paragraph_indent_margins(left, right)
{
    // =======================================================
    var idsetd = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
    var desc310 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    var ref27 = new ActionReference();
    var idPrpr = charIDToTypeID( "Prpr" );
    var idparagraphStyle = stringIDToTypeID( "paragraphStyle" );
    ref27.putProperty( idPrpr, idparagraphStyle );
    var idTxLr = charIDToTypeID( "TxLr" );
    var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
    var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
    ref27.putEnumerated( idTxLr, idOrdn, idTrgt );
    desc310.putReference( idnull, ref27 );
    var idT = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
    var desc311 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idtextOverrideFeatureName = stringIDToTypeID( "textOverrideFeatureName" );
    desc311.putInteger( idtextOverrideFeatureName, 808464435 );
    var idstartIndent = stringIDToTypeID( "startIndent" );
    var idPnt = charIDToTypeID( "#Pnt" );
    desc311.putUnitDouble( idstartIndent, idPnt, left );
    var idparagraphStyle = stringIDToTypeID( "paragraphStyle" );
    desc310.putObject( idT, idparagraphStyle, desc311 );
    executeAction( idsetd, desc310, DialogModes.NO );

    // =======================================================
    var idsetd = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
    var desc312 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    var ref28 = new ActionReference();
    var idPrpr = charIDToTypeID( "Prpr" );
    var idparagraphStyle = stringIDToTypeID( "paragraphStyle" );
    ref28.putProperty( idPrpr, idparagraphStyle );
    var idTxLr = charIDToTypeID( "TxLr" );
    var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
    var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
    ref28.putEnumerated( idTxLr, idOrdn, idTrgt );
    desc312.putReference( idnull, ref28 );
    var idT = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
    var desc313 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idtextOverrideFeatureName = stringIDToTypeID( "textOverrideFeatureName" );
    desc313.putInteger( idtextOverrideFeatureName, 808464436 );
    var idendIndent = stringIDToTypeID( "endIndent" );
    var idPnt = charIDToTypeID( "#Pnt" );
    desc313.putUnitDouble( idendIndent, idPnt, right );
    var idparagraphStyle = stringIDToTypeID( "paragraphStyle" );
    desc312.putObject( idT, idparagraphStyle, desc313 );
    executeAction( idsetd, desc312, DialogModes.NO );
}
```